# Why is the JVM total allocated memory greater than -Xmx?

Tags: java, memory, jvm-arguments

The JVM options:

> `-Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:SurvivorRatio=8`

As expected, the JVM will allocate almost 20MB memory for the JVM heap.

But please see the following GC detail:

> **PSYoungGen      total 9216K**, used 4612K [0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>    **eden space 8192K**, 56% used [0x00000000ff600000,0x00000000ffa812d8,0x00000000ffe00000)
>     **from space 1024K**, 0% used [0x00000000fff00000,0x00000000fff00000,0x0000000100000000)
>     **to   space** 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000fff00000)
>    **PSOldGen        total 10240K**, used 8192K [0x00000000fec00000, 0x00000000ff600000, 0x00000000ff600000)
>     object space 10240K, 80% used [0x00000000fec00000,0x00000000ff400020,0x00000000ff600000)
>    **PSPermGen       total 21248K**, used 3033K [0x00000000f9a00000, 0x00000000faec0000, 0x00000000fec00000)
>     object space 21248K, 14% used [0x00000000f9a00000,0x00000000f9cf6708,0x00000000faec0000)

The size of the *young generation* is as expected for the option `-Xmn`. The ratio of size for *eden space* and *survivor spaces* in the *young generation* is as expected for the option `-XX:SurvivorRatio=8`. **But** it seems in total the JVM allocated almost 40MB memory, so it is strange. Why is the JVM total allocated memory greater than `-Xmx`?

**Env:**

OS: win7 64 bit

JDK: build 1.6.0_43-b01 64bit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-Xmx` sets the maximum size of the HotSpot Object-Heap, that is the sum of YoungGen (Eden + Survivor-spaces) and OldGen and that is about 20 MB. The permanent generation resides outside this heap in a separate memory-area that is controlled via the `-XX:MaxPermSize` option.

Comment: so means the heap is devided into two generations: YoungGen and OldGen, not contains the PermGen?

Comment: @LipingHuang Yes, that is correct. The heap is divided into the *young generation*, `PSYoungGen`, and the *old generation*, `PSOldGen`. The heap does not contain the *permanent generation*, `PSPermGen`. By the way, `PS` stands for *parallel scavenge collector* (enabled using `-XX:UseParallelGC`).

Comment: @LipingHuang The *young generation* is further divided into the *eden space* and two *survivor spaces* known as the *from space* and *to space*. However, **only one of the *survivor spaces* contributes to the stated size of the *young generation***, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28347161/3460717).

Comment: @LipingHuang In case you are wondering why the total heap size (`PSYoungGen total 9216K` + `PSOldGen total 10240K` = `19456K` = 19MB) is less than the minimum heap size specified with `-Xms20M` then see the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28362435/3460717).

Comment: @DontDivideByZero The link post is removed. Any other references?