# Missing memory: size of young generation includes only one survivor space

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

On the Java heap, I **expected** that the size of the *young generation* would be the sum of the sizes of the *eden space* and **both of the *survivor spaces*** (*from space* and *to space*):

```
[young gen size] = [eden space size] + [from space size] + [to space size]
```

However, GC logs (using `XX:+PrintHeapAtGC`) state that the size of the *young generation* is the sum of the sizes of the *eden space* and **only one of the *survivor spaces***:

```
[young gen size] = [eden space size] + [from space size]
```

**Why does the size of the young generation only include the size of one survivor space?**

Maybe because **only one of the *survivor spaces* is available** at any time? But both *survivor spaces* exist so **both survivor spaces should contribute** to the size of the *new generation*?

GC log:

```
{Heap before GC invocations=48 (full 17):
par new generation   total 943744K, used 891496K [0x000000073ae00000, 0x000000077ae00000, 0x000000077ae00000)
  eden space 838912K, 100% used [0x000000073ae00000, 0x000000076e140000, 0x000000076e140000)
  from space 104832K,  50% used [0x000000076e140000, 0x000000077149a040, 0x00000007747a0000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x00000007747a0000, 0x00000007747a0000, 0x000000077ae00000)
```

From which:

```
[young gen size] = [eden space size] + [from space size]
     943744K     =      838912K      +      104832K
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any time one of the survivor spaces is always empty, so it cannot be considered available.