# Heap size is greater than -Xmx

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I set the initial and maximum Java heap size to 256MB using [`-Xms256m` and `-Xmx256m` JVM options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/3460717). The GC log (using `-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC`) states that the heap size is `251904K` (246MB), which is [smaller than the minimum heap size, `-Xms256m`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28362435/3460717) (see last line of log). However, this is because [the stated heap size is the **available** heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362436/3460717), which does not include [the **unavailable** *from space*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347161/missing-memory-size-of-young-generation-includes-only-one-survivor-space).

When I manually include the unavailable *from space* memory, the derived heap size is `262656K` (256.5MB), which is slightly **larger than the maximum heap size, `-Xmx`** (by 512KB):

```
[heap size] = [eden space size] + [from space size] + [to space size] + [OldGen size]
  262656K   =       66048K      +       10752K      +     10752K      + 175104K
```

**Why is the heap size slightly larger than the maximum heap size, `-Xmx`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly it seems strange, but as usual there is no magic. The only way to find out the answer is to go deeper: to the [openjdk sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/). Just checkout and try to grep: `grep -r "Xmx" .`

There will be many tests, but they are not interesting to us. Two files can help us: /vm/runtime/arguments.cpp and /vm/memory/collectorPolicy.cpp

Let's take a look at arguments.cpp: there is only simple parameters parsing, e.g. for `-Xmx256M` it will be something like `result = 256 * 1024 * 1024` (with some inlining from me). So there is no answer to our question.

But variable `MaxHeapSize` is initialized here, so we can try to find it. The real usage of `MaxHeapSize` can be found in our /vm/memory/collectorPolicy.cpp (where `Xmx` is used only in comments), where all heap generation sizes are are chosen by some policy.

If we skip all the details, we will find that all regions in heap should be aligned and region's sizes depends on ratio parameters.

The default JVM parameters for generation ratios are `-XX:NewRatio=2` (ratio of young gen:old gen sizes) and `-XX:SurvivorRatio=8` (ratio of eden:survivor gens). But heap size is not always divisible by 3, 9 or something else, so there should be some rounding. And, as I mentioned previously, there always should be some alignment.

**So, finally the answer**: these sizes are the only possible sizes to satisfy the conditions of generational ratios and alignment. It's just not always possible for sum of these values being equals to `Xmx` parameter value.

If you are interested in details, you can find the logic for rounding `-XX:NewRatio` [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/memory/collectorPolicy.cpp) in method `scale_by_NewRatio_aligned`.
Try to find the same logic about `-XX:SurvivorRatio` yourself :)